# Удаление лишних точек из числа

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Разрешен ввод в input только одной точки. Пытаюсь удалять из числа лишние точки, если их вводят.

Код:

```js
document.querySelector('.inputTest').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  // Регулярные выражения:
  var re = /,/g
  var re_2 = /\./g

  // Для замены запятой на точку
  if(this.value.match(re)){
    this.value = this.value.replace(re, '.')
  }

  // Если кол-во точек превысило более 1 шт.
  if(this.value.match(re_2) && this.value.match(re_2).length >= 2){
    this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.lastIndexOf('.'))
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inputTest {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <input class="inputTest" type="text" value="" placeholder="Число" />
```

При вводе одной точки всё хорошо, если ввести вторую точку (или более) за уже имеющейся точкой в конце числа - успешно обрезаются лишние точки и остается только одна. Пример:

```
// 555. => начальное число; 555... => после ввода лишних точек => 555. => Итог
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: если точка уже присутствует в числе и дополнительно ввести еще одну точку (или более) до имеющейся точки - обрезается всё справа от неё. Пример:

```
// 555.00 => начальное число; 55.5.00 => после ввода лишней точки => 55.5 => Итог
```

Необходимо, чтобы оставалась только одна точка в числе, а справа от введенной лишней точки ничего не удалялось - только лишняя точка удалялась, ну или лишние точки, если их введут много. При вводе запятой, пожалуйста, учтите. Пример:

```
// 555.00 => начальное число; 55.5.00 => после ввода лишней точки => 555.00 => Итог
// 555.00 => начальное число; 55...5.00 => после ввода лишних точек => 555.00 => Итог
// 555.00 => начальное число; 55,5.00 => после ввода запятой => 555.00 => Итог
```

Пытался сделать так:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/\./g, '')
```

Вместо:

```
this.value = this.value.substr(0, this.value.lastIndexOf('.'))
```

Не работает.

P.S. Input у меня разрешает только ввод чисел, запятой и точки.

Comment: На том пути, который Вы выбрали, у Вас в принципе нет возможности определить, какая из точек введена последней... запросто можно удалить "не ту", даже если доведёте до ума.

Comment: @Akina Согласен. Собственно данную проблему и пытаюсь решить)

Comment: В совсем другом языке (VB/VBA) для решения такой проблемы применяется обнуление кода введённого символа, если он невалиден (нулевой символ воспринимается как отсутствие ввода). Насколько этот подход применим в описанном случае - не скажу, не знаю. PS. Кстати, Вам ведь ещё после изменения текста и удаления второй точки желательно и курсор оставить там, где он был... тоже вряд ли тривиальная задача.

Comment: А может, легче поставить `input type="number"`? Или использовать regexp. Ну или готовые библиотеки есть, input mask например.